# CreateWindowExA interprets a regular string as Unicode, showing Chinese characters in title

Tags: winapi, visual-c++, unicode

Now, I know that in Microsoft's infinite wisdom they mistakenly name everything.  In Visual Studio the setting Unicode means UTF-16, and Multibyte characters is what Microsoft refers to as ANSI, which isn't ANSI at all, but Windows code page 1251.

Anyway, in WinAPI there are macro functions which call different functions, either the A or W version depending on whether Unicode is defined.  Everyone recommends to create code using Unicode.  So I set my settings to Unicode, and so the compiler expects the letter L before any string literals, or LPWSTR instead of LPSTR.  Problem is (it's not a huge problem), but in UTF-16 each character is either two or four bytes, mostly two bytes each.  I only intend to use ASCII characters mostly, so I actually call the A version of the functions even though Unicode is set.

Now, I was under the impression that this doesn't matter because ASCII is universal among all code pages and all Unicode encodings, that is, UTF-8, UTF-16, UTF-32, hell even the older ones, ASCII is pretty much universal, the first 127 characters, or at least roman alphabet and arabic numerals just DON'T change.

So my question is, having typed in "AAAAA" as my window title why does it come up with Chinese characters?  That's five As.  So I did a bit of research and found out that A Unicode is 0x0041, and two As is 0x4141, two bytes.  And this is the result.

[image]

So in a way, I kind of get why this is happening.  UTF-8 is so much better as it's only one byte for the ASCII characters and then more for the lesser used ones.  But the thing is, when I write in MessageBoxA or anything else with A, it comes up fine, it's only the window title that does this strange business.

Comment: Umm, as you can see from the code in the picture, I called CreateWindowExA(), which expects one byte characters, or chars, not wchar_t.  You can see the "AAAAA" that I passed as the window title.  The thing is that Visual Studio is set to Unicode, which is supposed to use the W version of the function.  But that still doesn't explain why this only happens on the window title and not anything else.

Comment: It looks to me like a Windows bug. Did you register the class in `wc` with `RegisterClassW` or `RegisterClassA`?

Comment: Is it possible that your window procedure is calling the wrong `DefWindowProc`?

Comment: @RaymondChen: I think you hit the nail. The docs, as I read them, say that if you use `RegisterClassW()` you must use `DefWindowProcW()` and if you use `RegisterClassA()` you must use `DefWindowProcA()`.

Comment: Show a [mcve] please

Comment: By the way, at the time Windows was designed, the Unicode Consortium recommended UCS-2 as the encoding for Unicode, so Microsoft was following the standard. The problem is that the standard changed a few years later, but by then it was too late.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Elaborating on the comments above, I think that the problem is that you are mixing Unicode and ANSI calls improperly. I mean, you can mix them, but you have to be careful.

In Windows there are two types of windows: Unicode windows and ANSI windows. You can tell the difference by calling [`IsWindowUnicode(HWND)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633529(v=vs.85).aspx).

The kind of window is determined when the window class is registered: use `RegisterClassA()` and you'll have an ANSI one; use `RegisterClassW()` and you'll have a Unicode one. Then the difference between these is in the messages received: a Unicode  window will receive Unicode messages and an ANSI window will receive ANSI messages.

Note that the kind of window does not depend on the use of `CreateWindowExA()` or `CreateWindowExW()`. It makes sense: the kind of window is determined by the designer of the window class, not by its user.

If then, for example, you call `SendMessageW()` with an ANSI window (or vice versa) and a well known message, Windows will automatically convert the charset of the `wParam` and `lParam` parameters.

So this is what I think it is happening:

1. You call `RegisterClassA()` to create an ANSI window class.
2. You call `CreateWindowExA()` but using the Unicode variant will change nothing.
3. In the window function you call `DefWindowProcW()` to do the default processing. Here is the error! An ANSI window should call `DefWindowProcA()`. Or better you should register the class with `RegisterClassW()`.
4. When the window is created the window caption is set by sending itself a [`WM_SETTEXT`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632644(v=vs.85).aspx). This message receives the text itself in `lParam` as a `LPCTSTR`.
5. Since your window is ANSI that `lParam` is actually an `LPCSTR` (ANSI string)
   pointing to your `"AAAAA"`. But you are passing it to `DefWindowProcW()` that expects a `LPCWSTR` (Unicode string). So you are effectively casting a pointer to ANSI string into a pointer to Unicode string.
6. You get garbled characters in the window caption.

Beware that the bad effects of this mismatch is not limited to the window caption. There are all sorts of bad behavior lurking in there!.

Comment: Spot on, when I change DefWindowProc to DefWindowProcA it comes out fine.  Wow, that was really awesome of you.  Yeah I'm aware that mixing ANSI and Unicode is asking for trouble, but come on, with a lot of code do you really have to have to have two bytes for each character?  UTF-8 would be great.  But I only tend to stick to the ASCII characters anyway.  Thanks.

Comment: @titone What problems are going to be caused with 2 bytes per char element?

Comment: Yeah I get what you mean, but say I'm loading dictionary words, and the difference is double, that's quite a difference.  The Roman alphabet being the most used on the net, UTF-8 has exploded recently as the standard. The thing about UTF-8 is that it's more complicated than simple ASCII. So if you have to write a string library or something... This graph is interesting about the growth of UTF-8  

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8#/media/File:UnicodeGrow2b.png   

Anyway, yeah you're right, it's not an issue, especially with plenty of RAM, just I'm super finicky.